# Swift Firebase Firestore userlist (too many reads)

Tags: swift, firebase, authentication

I'm trying to find a solution for a little problem I have with my app. It's a chess app and it works with Firebase and is written in swift. I use the database for user authentication, user information and uploading moves to play against each other online. All the userInfo is saved in a document in the collection "allUsers".

Everything is working fine, but I have a user screen where you can press a refresh button to update the current online users, with the `.getDocuments()` function. The problem is that every time a user refreshes, they query through **all** of the registered accounts, check if they have the flag "isOnline = true" and then list only those users in a TableView. I believe this counts in firebase as 1 read for every registered account, even though the user is not online.

The app is already live in the AppStore and I have quite a few people registered already. About 300. But, to be honest a lot of people just try it once or a few times and then leave again and never use the app again. But every time someone wants to update the online users, they cycle through 300 users and this gives me 300 reads with firebase. Right now it's not a big problem, but once people really start to use the app, I will reach my quotum quite quickly.

I could try `.addSnapshotListener` , but this will refresh the user screen everytime something happens in the userlist. It will be too chaotic. I've read about reading data from cache, but I'm not sure how to go about this. I could also get a fresh userlist when the app starts, save it locally and check every now and then if there are new online users, but I want the list to be updated whenever the user wants to.

Is there a way to compare a locally saved list to the online database list and only read/get the documents that are changed / new?

Sorry for the long text. Hopefully anyone can help me out!

Thanks.

Below is my code to load the users. It's a bit messy sorry.. Basically it retrieves all users and sorts them by online and offline. If a user searches for another user, it takes a String "query" as input.

Code :

```
func loadAllAvailableUsers(query : String) {

    availableEmails = []
    availableUsers = []
    onlineUsers = []
    isInGameIndex = []
    var av : [String] = []
    var ae : [String] = []
    var wins : [Int] = []
    var losses : [Int] = []
    var draw : [Int] = []
    var matches : [Int] = []
    let collection = db.collection("allUsers")
    collection.getDocuments { (snapshot, err) in
        if let e = err {
            print(e.localizedDescription)
        } else {

            if let documents = snapshot?.documents {

                print("found users")
                
                for doc in documents {
                    print(doc.documentID)
                    if doc.documentID != currentEmail && query == "" {
                        print(doc.data()["isOnline"] as! Bool)
                        if let name = doc.data()["username"] as? String, let w = doc.data()["wins"] as? Int, let l = doc.data()["losses"] as? Int, let d = doc.data()["draw"] as? Int, let numOfMatches = doc.data()["numberOfMatches"] as? Int, let online = doc.data()["isOnline"] as? Bool {
                            print("adding user : \(name) to list")
                            if online {
                                matches.append(numOfMatches)
                                av.append(name)
                                ae.append(doc.documentID)
                                wins.append(w)
                                losses.append(l)
                                draw.append(d)
                                onlineUsers.append(name)
                            if doc.data()["isInGame"] as! Bool == true {
                                print(i)
                                self.delegate?.addToInGameIndex(name: name)
                            }
                            }
                        }
                        
                    } else if query != "" {
                        if let name = doc.data()["username"] as? String, let w = doc.data()["wins"] as? Int, let l = doc.data()["losses"] as? Int, let d = doc.data()["draw"] as? Int, let online = doc.data()["isOnline"] as? Bool, let numOfMatches = doc.data()["numberOfMatches"] as? Int {
                             print("Searched : adding user : \(name) to list")
                            if doc.documentID == currentEmail {
                                continue
                            }
                            let lowerName = name.lowercased()
                            let lowerQuery = query.lowercased()
                            if lowerName.contains(lowerQuery) && online {
                             av.append(name)
                             ae.append(doc.documentID)
                                wins.append(w)
                                losses.append(l)
                                draw.append(d)
                                matches.append(numOfMatches)
                                if doc.data()["isInGame"] as! Bool == true {
                                    print(i)
                                    self.delegate?.addToInGameIndex(name: name)
                                }
                                onlineUsers.append(name)
                            } else if lowerName.contains(lowerQuery) && !online {
                                av.append(name)
                                ae.append(doc.documentID)
                                   wins.append(w)
                                   losses.append(l)
                                   draw.append(d)
                                   matches.append(numOfMatches)
                            }
                         }
                    }
                }

                
            }
            if ae.count > 0 {
            self.delegate?.reloadTheTable(wins: wins, losses: losses, draw: draw, ae: ae, au: av, matches: matches)
            }
            print(availableUsers)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Is this an overall design question? `.addSnapshotListener` adds a listener but only for the initial load, from there only the changes (add/change/remove). Firestore has a 50k/day read allowance on the free plan and $.06/100k on the blaze plan. See the note in the documentation [Changes Between Snapshots](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/listen#view_changes_between_snapshots). Saying *It will be too chaotic* is a vague as that could be just a design issue. I am not sure we can really provide any kind of answer here on SO since it's not really a coding question.

Comment: It's really hard to say how you can optimize code that we can't see, so I *highly* recommend including a [minimal, complete reproduction](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) in your question. But at a quick glance it sounds like you could [use a query](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries) to only get the documents for users that are currently online.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen I've added my code sorry. A query sounds like a way better way than I did now... Thanks! This would save me a lot of reads I guess. But is there also a way to compare offline saved documents/data to documents in the database? So that if nothing changes I don't have to load the document at all..

Comment: @Jay Hi thanks for your comment. What I meant with chaotic was, that I'd reload the tableview everytime something changes in the database when I add a listener. I would like the user to decide when to refresh the list of users. I've added my code

Comment: You don't need to do that! You can make granular updates based on the changes presented from Firestore. For example, take a look at the documentation [Changes between snapshots](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/listen#view_changes_between_snapshots). Imagine Player A takes a turn and moves a pawn and that's the only event. Your app will be notified of that in the .modified section and you can then update that one element in your dataSource and corresponding row in the tableView.

Comment: Hi @Jay. That's great thank you so much. Didn't know about this either! Perfect.